# Add users groups in Azure subscription using portal

Tags: powershell, security, azure

I was trying to follow this tutorial here from official Microsoft Docs in order to give in a specific user group a role.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure

I want that role to be applied on subscription level. First, the screenshots are outdated and they are not represent the current portal. Second, the current portal seems to be unable to find the user groups through the search.

Answer (score 1):

After searching and changing a lot of things I had realized that the issue wasn't on my action but on Azure portal. I gave up the portal and I started trying PowerShell and it works as it is expected to work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-manage-access-powershell

Therefore, save your time and use PowerShell instead of portal in case that you want to set a role in a user group. Again, there is no specific command as far as it concerns subscription level access. You need to modify a bit the one for Resource Groups and add -Scope. Your final command should be this:

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId $userGroupId -RoleDefinitionName 'Reader' -scope '/subscriptions/{Change_To_Subscription_ID}'
```